# When a cell is highlighted, I would like to subtract 8 from another cell to give total vacation hours available

Tags: excel

I am using a calendar in Excel that currently holds this formula:

```
=IF(AND(YEAR(JanSun1+4)=$A$1,MONTH(JanSun1+4)=1),JanSun1+4, "")
```

When I input someones vacation and highlight the cells green, I would like it to automatically subtract 8 from another cell in order to show what vacation time an employee still has. Could you help me with this? I understand that a colored cell does not equal data but I feel there should be a round-about way of doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you create a User Defined Function (via VBA), you **can** treat colored cells as data.  Alternatively, you can add a number to the cell and use conditional or normal formatting to hide the data in the background color.  This is pretty common if you want "invisible" data.

Answer (score 1):

I have a range of cells that auto highlight a cell that has the min value.  I then went back and made an `=if` with the same data that auto highlighted that cell and subtracted 10%.  If my last cell was the lowest value, I didn't want it to subtract.  Here's my formula: `=if(H5=min(B5:H5),"None",MIN(B5:H5)-10%)`
So basically could just take away the ,"none" part.

Don't just highlight the cells, but have a conditional formatting that highlights a cell with certain text and then use that same formatting in your formula.